# random letters/numbers after adding print document

Tags: vb.net

I need help after adding print document print dialog to my project there are random letters/numbers in my datagridview

[image]

Comment: If it's not working then you did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did then we can't tell you what's wrong with it. We should have to tell you to provide the relevant code. Maybe you should have taken the site tour when prompted and learned how to write a proper question.

Comment: The only answer we can provide, based on the information you gave us, is to remove the print dialog.